# In gnuplot for Windows, how can I list the files in the current/working directory?

Tags: gnuplot

I am running `gnuplot` version 4.6 (patchlevel 0) for Windows.  The Windows version of this program provides a console or command prompt interface, similar to a `bash` shell in Unix/Linux or the DOS **Command Prompt** in Windows.

Some commands in `gnuplot` for Windows are similar to those in Unix/Linux or DOS.  For example, `pwd` prints the  current/working directory.  Also, `cd` changes the directory, so I can use commands like `cd 'C:\Documents and Settings'`.

However, I have oddly not been able to figure out how to list the files in the current/working directory (which in Unix/Linux would be `ls` and in DOS would be `dir`).  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: download a copy of a Linux distro of your choice.  replace (preferable) or dual-boot with your current OS.  Install gnuplot via the package manager.  Use the answer provided by `Qiau` ;^).  In all seriousness, a user earlier today mentioned using gnuplot_pipes.exe.  I don't know what it is, but it might be worth lookinginto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick code review of Gnuplot 4.6.0 shows that `ls` (or similar) isn't supported in windows.

You can however use the `system` command, like `system 'dir'`

Comment: Thanks.  What do you mean by "code review"?  I looked in the manual, and I didn't see any command like `ls`, like you said.

Comment: Updated the answer with an solution I found too.

Comment: Unfortunately, `system 'dir'` does not work on my system (Windows XP).  When I enter it into the `gnuplot` prompt, a Windows/DOS **Command Prompt** appears to open and then close immediately; the output of `dir` is not rerouted/redirected to the `gnuplot` prompt/terminal.

Comment: Oh, I downloaded http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.6.0/gp460win32.zip/download and there `!dir` also works (as well as `system 'dir'`, `system 'ls'` and `!ls`). But I'm running Windows 7 x64. The executable should however be runnable in XP too. I'm running gnuplot.exe.

Comment: You are probably running `wgnuplot.exe`. Both `system` and `!` spawns a shell that executes the command. There is unfortunately no way to use the output within wgnuplot.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see a listing of the working directory from within the Windows gnuplot console, the following works for me, but use backticks:

```
`dir && pause`
```

or alternatively

```
system("dir && pause")
```

This will open separate cmd window and keep it open until you hit a key.

Answer (score 0):

Since you might need only the file names for a script you could use

```
FILES = system("dir *.txt /B")
```

the  **/B**  gets rid of the header, summary and additional information.